# How to convert only one project from an svn repository to git?

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to convert a svn repository to git, but the repository has 3 projects and I only want one (which has tags and trunk), the tree below shows the repository.

```
project
├── tags
│   ├── v1_project1
│   └── v1_project2
└── trunk
    ├── project1
    ├── project2
    └── project3
```

I want to convert only project1 (project1, v1_project1). Does anyone know how I can do this?

**EDITED**

I tried converting using svn2git from that link: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

But I did not understand what it means `--no-minimize-url`:

```
  svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo/nested_project --no-minimize-url
```

Comment: And then you also have v1_project1, v2_project1, v3_project1, v1_project2, v2_project2, and so on... all of them inside project/tags? No branches directory?

Comment: Has one but it's empty.

Comment: That is why I recommend subit instead of svn2git: more flexible and precise.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use [`subgit.com`](https://subgit.com/) (which has a [free option](https://subgit.com/pricing), handy for a one time export/import).

It can accommodate unconventional [trunk/branch/tag mapping](https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, no branches other than the trunk. With git-svn you can specifically specify the directory where the tags or branches are... of course, it's not *standard* layout so you **won't** use `-s`. You will use something like `-t project/tags/*_project1 -T project/trunk/project1`. You can specify multiple of each if necessary.